# How do I hook up the code to change Drupal module behaviour?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Drupal does not allow me to delete extension (recurring_commerce) as some fields needs to be deleted manually. This issue is described in detalis below.

Solution is to add some code to a file as described in #11 of the issue below.

Basically I need to programmatically delete a field and I have never done it before. Writing kind of a hook (?).

I tried to paste the suggested code before, after the original code as well as replacing the original code with a suggested one.

Every time after changing the code I am restarting the server, running cron and clear cache.

Still I am unable to uninstall the exension from drupal as I have the following message:

```
The following reason prevents Commerce Recurring from being uninstalled:

    The Billing period field type is used in the following fields: commerce_order.billing_period, commerce_order_item.billing_period
```

Details of the following issue:

please skip to #11

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/2924965

Suggested code to apply:

```
function commerce_recurring_update_8101(&$sandbox) {

\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order.recurring.billing_period')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order.recurring.billing_schedule')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order.recurring.order_items')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order_item.recurring_standalone.billing_period')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order_item.recurring_standalone.subscription')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order_item.recurring_product_variation.billing_period')->delete();
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('commerce_order_item.recurring_product_variation.subscription')->delete();
}

function commerce_recurring_update_8102(&$sandbox) {
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_type')->load('recurring')->delete();
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item_type')->load('recurring_standalone')->delete();
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item_type')->load('recurring_product_variation')->delete();

}
```

Original code in my file:

```
/**
 * Add the 'trial_starts' and "trial_ends" fields to subscriptions.
 */
function commerce_recurring_update_8101(&$sandbox) {
  $fields = [];
  $fields['trial_starts'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('timestamp')
    ->setLabel(t('Trial starts'))
    ->setDescription(t('The time when the subscription trial starts.'))
    ->setRequired(FALSE)
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'timestamp',
      'weight' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'datetime_timestamp',
      'weight' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

  $fields['trial_ends'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('timestamp')
    ->setLabel(t('Trial ends'))
    ->setDescription(t('The time when the subscription trial ends.'))
    ->setRequired(FALSE)
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'timestamp',
      'weight' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'datetime_timestamp',
      'weight' => 0,
 ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'datetime_timestamp',
      'weight' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

  $update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  foreach ($fields as $name => $storage_definition) {
    $update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition($name, 'commerce_subscription', 'commerce_recurring', $storage_definition);
  }
}

/**
 * Make the billing_schedule field required on subscriptions.
 */
function commerce_recurring_update_8102() {
  $entity_definition_update = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $field_definition = $entity_definition_update->getFieldStorageDefinition('billing_schedule', 'commerce_subscription');
  $field_definition->setRequired(TRUE);
  $entity_definition_update->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field_definition);
}
```